# jQuery parameter for a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I am using now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#btn2').click(function(){

    $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-image', 'url(http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/1.png)');
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('opacity', 1.0);

 });
});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<select onchange="bg(this[this.selectedIndex].value);">
 <option value="0.png" id="btn1">1. Default skin</option>
 <option value="1.png" id="btn2">2. MK7 Collage</option>
 <option value="1.png" id="btn3">3. Solid Queen</option>
</select>
```

When I click the `2. MK7 Collage`, as you can see in my jQuery function, the background of my iframe changes.

I have 3 option values and each one has a different background and id. I'd like to change them everytime a 'option value' is clicked. It's like:

```
 $('#the_optionvalue_id').click(function(background_image_url){

        $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-image', 'url(background_image_url)');
        $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('opacity', 1.0);

     });
```

I am pretty new with jQuery and I don't know how to set the id (`the_optionvalue_id`) and the `background_image_url` every time that a `option` is selected. Any help?

Comment: "I don't know how to set the id (the_optionvalue_id) and the background_image_url with HTML." - ok, slow down, I don't understand a word. what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: '$('#the_optionvalue_id').click(function(background_image_url){' Here I wanna change the value of 'the_optionvalue_id' and and the 'background_image_url' every time I click an 'option'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
<select id="bgselector">
 <option value="0.png" id="btn1">1. Default skin</option>
 <option value="1.png" id="btn2">2. MK7 Collage</option>
 <option value="1.png" id="btn3">3. Solid Queen</option>
</select>
```

then put all your jQuery code inside the ready function :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var iframe_body = $('iframe').contents().find('body'); //cache this for performance;

    var set_bg = function(url) {
        iframe_body.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + url + ')',
            'opacity': 1.0);
        });
    }

    $('#bgselector').change(function() {
        set_bg($(this).val());
    });

    $('#btn2').click(function(){
        set_bg('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/1.png');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This code works perfectly, I'm going to accept the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Does JQuery not cache selections automatically? I've worked more with YUI, which if I recall does, but I'm not sure about JQuery

Comment: As far as I can it doesn't cache, you can chain but that wouldn't work for this case.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you don't need to add a click event since you already call a function named `bg` each time the value changes. You may just declare your function somewhere :

```
function bg(value) {
    var base = 'http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/';
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + (base + value) + ')',
        'opacity': 1
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/jJPKA/)***

Basically you should keep a string with the value of the directory where the files sit, and then using the `change` method of jquery change the value of the css when the select changes. Here is a simple example using a div to show the output of the value:

html

```
<div id="body">http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/0.png</div>
<select id="sel">
 <option value="0.png" id="btn1">1. Default skin</option>
 <option value="1.png" id="btn2">2. MK7 Collage</option>
 <option value="2.png" id="btn3">3. Solid Queen</option>
</select>
```

js

```
var base = "http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/";
$("#sel").change(function(){
 $("#body").html(base + this.value); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you can have a function return a function. The outer function can take a parameter, so then you would have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clickHandlerGenerator = function(url) {
    return function(){
        $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');
        $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('opacity', 1.0);
    });
    $('#btn2').click(clickHandlerGenerator('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/1.png'));
    $('#btn1').click(clickHandlerGenerator('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/WHATEVER.png'));
}
```